# What to include in headers when making preflight complex CORS request?

Tags: node.js, express, cors, axios, session-cookies

An app I'm making has the front-end and node-back end hosted separately (cross origin). The front-end is making a call to the back end for login where the x-session-token is sent back. Because this is a custom header I understand this to be a complex request and therefore a pre-flight check is needed.

In the server.js file I have the following snippet (which I understand to enable CORS pre-flight checks):

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
}

app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

The front-end makes the following axios call:

```
axios.post('/api/user/login', logInObj,
    {withCredentials:true},
    {crossDomain:true},
    {'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Content-Type'},
    {'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'post'}
    )
    .then(logInResponse => ...
```

Which is responded to by this in the back-end:

```
router.post('/api/user/login', (request, response) => {
...
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Method', 'get', 'post', 'options');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', request.get('Origin'));
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age','86400')
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
...
```

When I console log the response header on the back-end it contains:

An x-session-token matches that in MySQL

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is listed as http://localhost:3000 not wildcard (*)

However the console.log of the response in the browser has null for the session-token which tells me the browser is blocking the CORS return data (X-Session-Token in this case). What am I missing in the request or response header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss the exposed Header you want to send back.
"x-session-token" ?
Also try to use app.use instead of just app.options and let the cors package handle it unless it is just specific to this route of course

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true, 
  exposedHeaders: ['Set-Cookie', 'Content-Length', 'Accept', 'X-Requested-With', 'X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'x-session-token' ],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
})
```

Comment: Oh my goodness that worked! Claudio you're a saint! If you have you a moment would you mind elaborating on the pitfalls of using app.options vs app.use?

Comment: app.use before your router declaration will always apply the cors middleware to all your routes before the routes middlewares get called.

Comment: Thanks @Claudio Viola. Might you know why this only works in the development and not the production environment? (The origin is changed to the production url)

Comment: are you using HTTPS ? How does production differ? where is the service pushed to?

Comment: Thanks @Claudio Viola. The production client side build and server are hosted separately via https on Heroku. Would the links to each be helpful? Perhaps headers need to added to the exposed list in production?

Comment: Have you made sure the origin url is using the right url with https in front?

Comment: thanks again. Your initial answer still holds, my issue was a database connection error instead